# Is it Possible to use Reserve with Integral number in C++?

Tags: c++

i want to reverse the position of integer like this :

x = 2 
y = 10 
Result : 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 
After Reversed : 10 | 8 | 6 | 4 | 2

My Question is... Can i using these code :

```
reverse(x.begin(),
x.end());
```

Check my syntax these below :

```
int x;
int y;


cout<<"Input your numbers = ";
cin>>x;
cout<<"Last Result =";
cin>>y;

while (x < y){ 
cout<<x<<"|"; 
x+=2;

reverse(x.begin(),
x.end());
cout << x << endl;
```

I get error with those Syntax, so please,,, Help me..

> Sorry for my Bad Grammar

Comment: "I get error with those Syntax" First step: Figure out what sort of error you get.

Comment: There's nothing to reverse since you haven't saved any number. `reverse` is an operation for containers. if you want to print the numbers between x and y from y, hopping two numbers each iteration, don't contaminate x in your first loop (use a different variable), and then run from y to x (using `-= 2`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **vector**, here is how to do it:

```
vector<int> vex; 

while( x < y) {
       cout << x << "|";
       x += 2 
       vex.push_back(x);
}

auto r_begin = vex.rbegin();
auto r_end = vex.rend();

while ( r_begin != r_end ) {
      cout << r_begin << "|";
      ++r_begin; // here incrementing means going to previous element
 }
```

Comment: Thank you :)
But wait,, i cant get it ,, what this mean ==> push_back(x); ?

Comment: It simply means that take the value x and place it at the back of vex.

Comment: And when you're using push_back(args) it will keep on appending args to the back of the container on which push_back(args) is called on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [`std::reverse`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) which seems like what you want.  However, you are trying to call it with an int instead of a container.  You need to store the ints you are creating into a container such as a vector:

```
int x;
int y;


cout<<"Input your numbers = ";
cin>>x;
cout<<"Last Result = ";
cin>>y;

vector<int> numbers;

while (x <= y)
{ 
    cout<<x<<"|";
    numbers.push_back(x);
    x+=2;
}

reverse(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
cout << endl;

for (int num : numbers)
{
    cout << num << "|";
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)
I hope this will solved my Problem :)

#HellGrammar :V